# feeding data labels into excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have a scatter plot graph

i would like each dot to have a label.

how do i feed in labels through VBA for each dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after the [ApplyDataLabels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221818%28office.11%29.aspx) method. Make sure you read the documentation, it has a lot of optional parameters.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim sc As Excel.Series
    For Each sc In Chart2.SeriesCollection
        sc.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue, True, True, False, True
    Next
End Sub
```